# change variable value in CoffeeScript scope

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to change the variable value in CoffeeScript but can't seem to do it.

Here is my code:

```
myfunction: ->
   first_variable = 1
   if first_variable == 1
      first_variable = 2
   alert first_variable  #alert gives me 1
```

But `first_variable` remains 1. What changes are required to change the value?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in defining the function. Below code works fine for me:

```
myfunction= ->
   first_variable = 1
   if first_variable == 1
      first_variable = 2
   alert first_variable 

myFunction() #alert will give 2
```

For more info: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/coffeescript/coffeescript_functions.htm